# ¿Dónde colocar atributos en Widget con estados?

Tags: flutter, dart, parametros

En flutter existen los StateFul widget, ejemplo:

```dart
class PlanetFormAdder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlanetFormAdderState createState() => _PlanetFormAdderState();
}

class _PlanetFormAdderState extends State<PlanetFormAdder> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Teniendo ese pequeño ejemplo como referencia, ¿dónde sería mejor colocar el atributo: `final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();`? ¿Dentro de la clase que extiende de `StatefulWidget` o dentro de la clase que estiende de `State<PlanetFormAdder>`?

Pregunto, dado que creo que se puede acceder a los atributos de la clase `PlanetFormAdder` desde la clase `_PlanetFormAdderState`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación que haces en el ejemplo es la correcta y estándar.

Los atributos de un Widget deben ir dentro de la clase que extiende de State para poder acceder desde los propios Widgets que vas a renderizar, si estuviesen en el que extiende de StatefulWidget no serían accesibles. ;)